# Azure cognitive Service API providing different sentiment score than web version

Tags: azure, api

I am calling the Azure cognitive Service API in Power Apps using the following code:

```
If( chkSentiment.Value = true,
    ClearCollect( sentimentCollect, 
        TextAnalytics.DetectSentimentV2(
            {
                language: "en", 
                text: tiTextToAnalyze.Text
            }
        ).score
    )
)
```

as seen in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/cognitive-services-api

Everything about the API call seems so be working properly, except when I get the score back it is different from the score I get when I enter the same text in the web version: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/#features

What could be causing this issue?